# Show only one product on page by specific tag in shopify

Tags: shopify, product

```
<div class="row">
    {% for product in collections.all.products %}
         {% if product.tags contains 'frontpagedeal' %}
                  {% if product.price_min < product.compare_at_price_min %}
                       {% include 'today-sale' %}
                  {% endif %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
```

I try below code but this is also not working.

```
 <div class="row">
          {% for product in collections.Daily_Deals.products %}
                 {% if product.tags contains 'frontpagedeal' %}  

                    {% include 'dailydeal-countdown' %} 

          {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

  </div>
```

how I can display a only one product with specific tag ??

Answer (score 0):

```
 {% for product in collections.Daily_Deals.products %}
     {% if product.tags contains 'frontpagedeal' %}
         {% if forloop.first == true %}
            {% include 'dailydeal-countdown' %}
         {% endif %}
     {% endif %}
 {% endfor %}
```

Can you please test this and tell me if this is what you want.

all i did is adding  `{% if forloop.first == true %} .... {% endif %}`  which will display only one product.

Comment: I am trying that     {% for product in collections.all.products %}
          {% if product.tags contains 'frontpagedeal' %}  
             
              {% include 'dailydeal-countdown' %} 
          {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}   but no product show

Answer (score 0):

In your second example handles are always lower case so:

```
<div class="row">
{% assign oneShown = false %}
      {% for product in collections.daily_deals.products %}
          {% if oneShown %}
             {% break %}
          {% endif %}
          {% if product.tags contains 'frontpagedeal' %}  
              {% include 'dailydeal-countdown' %} 
              {% assign oneShown = true %}
          {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Should work. However if your collection has more than 50 products you may not find the product you are looking for so you'll need to make sure the collection has fewer than 50 products. Ideally for something like this "Daily Deals" would be a smart collection that includes products based on them being a 'frontpagedeal' and you can skip the tag check.

Comment: What is this 250 limit?

Comment: I try your code but not output and i also try that but nothing show   {% for product in collections.all.products %}
          {% if product.tags contains 'frontpagedeal' %}  
             
              {% include 'dailydeal-countdown' %} 
          {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

Comment: Sorry -- limit is 50. I must have just read the 250 image limit when I wrote that. (or something -- I'm sure there's a reasonable explanation :-)

Comment: You'd need to tell us more about how your collection is set up. My original would have worked display all the products in Daily Deals tagged with frontpagedeal. @mash-r's won't work unless the tagged product is the first one in the collection. I just fixed mine to only show one product.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be useful to create a "sale collection" directly in store administration and display it then.

If it is for a client, you may add an option to theme to allow client to select sale collection in theme settings.

Comment: No i dont want to add more collection like "Sale collection" Just i want to show a single product at front page according to my wish without creating any collection , I select a product from any collection and show at front page with specific tag.

Comment: Hello. Shopify limits query at 50 products per page. So, in your collection, if the product is the 51th or more it won't be found in the loop. So the solution would be to sort the collection to place the product as first (or at least before th 50th rank). By the way another solution would be to add a product selection in theme settings and display it. Or another way : a linklist.